# WPF MahApps.Metro Resources not found

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I updated the Packages recently and since then my recourses are not found anymore.
Only the Controls and the Fonts are found but not the rest which i find really confusing.
Did anyone had a similar problem?
BR Max

```
<Application x:Class="Tools.Shell.App"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Tools.Shell">
        <Application.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <!-- MahApps.Metro resource dictionaries. Make sure that all file names are Case Sensitive! -->
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                    <!-- Accent and AppTheme setting -->
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Teal.xaml" />
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
                    <!-- Button Theme setting -->
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/FlatButton.xaml" />
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Application.Resources>
    </Application>
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case of. when you upgrade a package, always check the documents for breaking changes

[Migration to v2.0](https://mahapps.com/docs/guides/migration-to-v2.0)

> **Theming**
>
> The theming got rewritten, this means that there is no longer a
> separation between AppTheme and Accent. These got replaced by Theme
> everywhere. Instead of something like
> pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml
> and
> pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml
> you now have to use
> pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Themes/Light.Blue.xaml.

**Old**

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**New**

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Themes/Light.Blue.xaml" />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

<sub>***Note** : I don't use this package (or any of his stuff), there may be more to this story, however at least it might point you in the right direction. You need to read the rest of the documentation about migration*</sub>